# How to reference to a schema inside the same collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to store forms' questions and answers in the same collection. Here's the Model and schemas I've designed:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  type: String,
  title: String,
});

const answerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  question: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Form.questions",
  },
  answer: String,
});

const Form = mongoose.model("Form", {
  title: { type: String, default: "Titre du formulaire" },
  questions: [questionSchema],
  answers: [[answerSchema]],
});

module.exports = Form;
```

For each answer, I'm trying to reference the objectId of the question, but `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` seems to work only when referencing to another collection, not to some other id in the same collection. I don't know what to put instead of `ref: "Form.questions"` to get populate() to display the question in the answer.

Am I on the right track, how can I connect properly an answer to its question? Or do I need to create a separate collection for the answers?

Here's an example of the output:

```
{
    "title": "Formulaire de test",
    "answers": [
        [
            {
                "_id": "5fd8f8938a111d3a1df9f3bd",
                "question": "5fd8a65ae252ae5b903d4593",
                "answer": "Question 1"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fd8f8938a111d3a1df9f3be",
                "question": "5fd8a65ae252ae5b903d4595",
                "answer": "Question 3"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fd8f8938a111d3a1df9f3bf",
                "question": "5fd8a65ae252ae5b903d4594",
                "answer": "Question 2"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fd8f8938a111d3a1df9f3c0",
                "question": "5fd8f6898a111d3a1df9f3bb",
                "answer": "Question 4"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fd8f8938a111d3a1df9f3c1",
                "question": "5fd8f6898a111d3a1df9f3bc",
                "answer": "Question 5"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "_id": "5fd8f96a9d75193ecd410464",
                "question": "5fd8a65ae252ae5b903d4593",
                "answer": "Question 1"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fd8f96a9d75193ecd410465",
                "question": "5fd8a65ae252ae5b903d4595",
                "answer": "Question 3"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fd8f96a9d75193ecd410466",
                "question": "5fd8a65ae252ae5b903d4594",
                "answer": "Question 2"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fd8f96a9d75193ecd410467",
                "question": "5fd8f6898a111d3a1df9f3bb",
                "answer": "Question 4"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5fd8f96a9d75193ecd410468",
                "question": "5fd8f6898a111d3a1df9f3bc",
                "answer": "Question 5"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "_id": "5fd8f4c5600d65378596748a",
    "questions": [
        {
            "_id": "5fd8a65ae252ae5b903d4593",
            "title": "Question 1",
            "type": "text"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd8a65ae252ae5b903d4595",
            "title": "Question 3",
            "type": "text"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd8a65ae252ae5b903d4594",
            "title": "Question 2",
            "type": "score"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd8f6898a111d3a1df9f3bb",
            "title": "Question 4",
            "type": "text"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd8f6898a111d3a1df9f3bc",
            "title": "Question 5",
            "type": "text"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 3
}
```